# Print_r Paginate Results

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My print_r result returns 100+ Results. How can I add pagination to display 10 results at a time?

```
<a href="<?php print_r($link);?>"> <?php print_r($link);?> </a>
```

Comment: What does $link contain

Comment: @NigelRen Just a url string

Comment: This is lacking a lot of relevant information.  Where's the rest of the code related to this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an array? If yes, you could just use

```
$output = array_slice($link, 0, 10);
print($output);
```

in this code, it would print the first 10 from the array in the `$output` var.

Comment: Just a URL string Pulled from the DB